# Error when trying to insert values into a table and not sure why

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g

I am using Oracle and I am trying to insert values into a table called bug but i am not sure what it means and how to fix it.

My error can be seen below:

Error starting at line : 78 in command -
INSERT INTO Bug(Bug_ID, Bug_Type, Bug_Desc, Bug_Time) VALUES (00, 'Crash', 'Software stopped functioning properly and exited', DATE '1980-03-20 09:26:50')

> Error at Command Line : 78 Column : 133 Error report - SQL Error:
>   ORA-01861: literal does not match format string
>   01861. 00000 -  "literal does not match format string"
>
> *Cause:    Literals in the input must be the same length as literals in
>              the format string (with the exception of leading whitespace).  If the
>              "FX" modifier has been toggled on, the literal must match exactly,
>              with no extra whitespace.
>
> *Action:   Correct the format string to match the literal.

Any help will be greatly appreciated.

My code so far can be seen below:

```
--CREATE SCRIPTS
/*put your create scripts here – your script should not commented out*/

CREATE TABLE Project
(
    Proj_ID integer,
    Proj_Name varchar(10),
    Proj_Start_Date date,
    primary key (Proj_ID)
);

CREATE TABLE Bug
(
    Bug_ID integer,
    Bug_Type varchar(40),
    Bug_Desc varchar(20),
    Bug_Time date,
    primary key(Bug_ID)
);

CREATE TABLE Engineer
(
    Engineer_ID integer,
    Engineer_Name varchar(10),
    Engineer_Type varchar(20),
    primary key (Engineer_ID)
);

CREATE TABLE Bug_Project
(
    Bug_ID integer,
    Proj_ID integer,
    primary key(Bug_ID, Proj_ID),
    foreign key(Bug_ID) references Bug (Bug_ID),
    foreign key(Proj_ID) references  Project (Proj_ID)
);

CREATE TABLE Fix_Allocation
(
    Engineer_ID integer,
    Bug_ID integer,
    primary key(Engineer_ID, Bug_ID),
    foreign key(Engineer_ID) references Engineer (Engineer_ID),
    foreign key(Bug_ID) references Bug (Bug_ID)
);

CREATE TABLE Test_Allocation
(
    Engineer_ID integer,
    Bug_ID integer,
    primary key(Engineer_ID, Bug_ID),
    foreign key(Engineer_ID) references Engineer (Engineer_ID),
    foreign key(Bug_ID) references Bug (Bug_ID)
);

CREATE TABLE Note
(
    Engineer_ID integer,
    Bug_ID integer,
    Note_author varchar(10),
    Note_contents varchar(20),
    primary key(Engineer_ID, Bug_ID),
    foreign key(Engineer_ID) references Engineer (Engineer_ID),
    foreign key(Bug_ID) references Bug (Bug_ID)
);

COMMIT;
--INSERT SCRIPTS
/*put your insert scripts here – your script should not commented out */

INSERT INTO Project(Proj_ID, Proj_Name, Proj_Start_Date) VALUES (00, 'Project 1', DATE '1980-02-14');
INSERT INTO Project(Proj_ID, Proj_Name, Proj_Start_Date) VALUES (01, 'Project 2', DATE '1985-12-11');
INSERT INTO Project(Proj_ID, Proj_Name, Proj_Start_Date) VALUES (02, 'Project 3', DATE '1992-06-03');
INSERT INTO Project(Proj_ID, Proj_Name, Proj_Start_Date) VALUES (03, 'Project 4', DATE '2000-07-22');
INSERT INTO Project(Proj_ID, Proj_Name, Proj_Start_Date) VALUES (04, 'Project 5', DATE '2012-03-19');
INSERT INTO Project(Proj_ID, Proj_Name, Proj_Start_Date) VALUES (05, 'Project 6', DATE '2015-10-21');

INSERT INTO Bug(Bug_ID, Bug_Type, Bug_Desc, Bug_Time) VALUES (00, 'Crash', 'Software stopped functioning properly and exited', DATE '1980-03-20 09:26:50');
INSERT INTO Bug(Bug_ID, Bug_Type, Bug_Desc, Bug_Time) VALUES (01, 'Run Time Error', 'Wrong output due to a logical error', DATE '1982-06-31 11:36:32');
INSERT INTO Bug(Bug_ID, Bug_Type, Bug_Desc, Bug_Time) VALUES (02, 'Compilation Error', 'Problems with the compiler, failed complication of source code', DATE '1987-07-12 14:11:15');
INSERT INTO Bug(Bug_ID, Bug_Type, Bug_Desc, Bug_Time) VALUES (03, 'Crash', 'Software stopped functioning properly and exited', DATE '1993-01-31 03:21:17');
INSERT INTO Bug(Bug_ID, Bug_Type, Bug_Desc, Bug_Time) VALUES (04, 'Logical Error', 'Unexpected behavior due to problem in source code', DATE '1997-04-01 10:46:18');
INSERT INTO Bug(Bug_ID, Bug_Type, Bug_Desc, Bug_Time) VALUES (05, 'Run Time Error', 'Wrong output due to a logical error', DATE '2001-12-24 12:12:37');
INSERT INTO Bug(Bug_ID, Bug_Type, Bug_Desc, Bug_Time) VALUES (06, 'GUI Error', 'Glitchy interface ', DATE '2005-09-02 17:11:55');

INSERT INTO Engineer(Engineer_ID, Engineer_Name, Engineer_Type) VALUES (00, 'Ava', 'Tester');
INSERT INTO Engineer(Engineer_ID, Engineer_Name, Engineer_Type) VALUES (01, 'Alexander', 'Fixer');
INSERT INTO Engineer(Engineer_ID, Engineer_Name, Engineer_Type) VALUES (02, 'Aiden', 'Fixer');
INSERT INTO Engineer(Engineer_ID, Engineer_Name, Engineer_Type) VALUES (03, 'Anthony', 'Tester');
INSERT INTO Engineer(Engineer_ID, Engineer_Name, Engineer_Type) VALUES (04, 'Adam', 'Fixer');
INSERT INTO Engineer(Engineer_ID, Engineer_Name, Engineer_Type) VALUES (05, 'Alex', 'Tester');
INSERT INTO Engineer(Engineer_ID, Engineer_Name, Engineer_Type) VALUES (06, 'John', 'Fixer');

INSERT INTO Bug_Project VALUES ();
INSERT INTO Bug_Project VALUES ();
INSERT INTO Bug_Project VALUES ();

INSERT INTO Fix_Allocation VALUES ();
INSERT INTO Fix_Allocation VALUES ();
INSERT INTO Fix_Allocation VALUES ();

INSERT INTO Test_Allocation VALUES ();
INSERT INTO Test_Allocation VALUES ();
INSERT INTO Test_Allocation VALUES ();

INSERT INTO Note VALUES ();
INSERT INTO Note VALUES ();
INSERT INTO Note VALUES ();

COMMIT;
--SELECT SCRIPT
/*put your select scripts here (with indication of which query is answered) – your script should not commented out

-- Query 1:  List of all the bugs, and their details.
SELECT * FROM Bug;

-- Query 2: List of all bugs, and their notes.

-- Query 3: List of all bugs, with their notes, and the engineers who have written them; sorted by name of engineer.

-- Query 4: List the bugs and how much cumulative time (in hours) they have taken; ordered by time taken.

-- Query 5: The bug that has taken most time to fix, and the projects it is connected to.

COMMIT;
--DROP SCRIPT
/*put your drop scripts here (in the correct order)– your script should not commented out

DROP TABLE Note;
DROP TABLE Test_Allocation;
DROP TABLE Fix_Allocation;
DROP TABLE Engineer;
DROP TABLE Bug_Project;
DROP TABLE Bug;
DROP TABLE Project;

COMMIT;
```

EDIT:

```
INSERT INTO Bug(Bug_ID, Bug_Type, Bug_Desc, Bug_Time) VALUES (01, 'Run Time Error', 'Wrong output due to a logical error', To_DATE ('1982-06-31 11:36:32', 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MO:SS'));
```

This is the error message i got:

Error starting at line : 79 in command -
INSERT INTO Bug(Bug_ID, Bug_Type, Bug_Desc, Bug_Time) VALUES (01, 'Run Time Error', 'Wrong output due to a logical error', To_DATE ('1982-06-31 11:36:32', 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MO:SS'))
Error report -
ORA-01821: date format not recognized

Comment: the format mask for minutes is `MI`, so your `to_date()` should have the format mask  of `yyyy-mm-dd-hh24:mi:ss` (caps or lower case, it doesn't matter). However, you have another problem: the 31st June doesn't exist (June only has 30 days).

Comment: Yeah I realised my mistake on that haha, thank you

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Date function can only take `'YYYY-MM-DD'` format.

`DATE '1982-06-31 11:36:32'` is wrong.

You can use to_date for it as following.

```
To_DATE ('1982-06-31 11:36:32,'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS') 
-- hour in 24 hour format as can be seen in other dates in your example.
-- if your date contains AM or PM then you can use, To_DATE ('1982-06-31 11:36:32 AM' ,'YYYY-MM-DD HH:MI:SS AM')
```

Cheers!!

Comment: I tried to implement this but it gave me an error still saying data type is not recognised. I will add the error and code above

Comment: What is the actual error? And which statement gave you this error? Also last 12 insert statements are totally invalid. And number 00 will be 0 and 01 will be 1. There is no need of 0 infront of the number.

Comment: Yes I am aware but how what do you mean invalid and which ones are you talking about?

Comment: In your question, 12 insert statements before commit are invalid

Answer (score 1):

When you have a time component, use a `TIMESTAMP` literal rather than `DATE` literal:

```
TIMESTAMP '2005-09-02 17:11:55'
```

You can insert this value into a `DATE`.

Comment: I tried this and it got rid of the error but in the table outputted it only has the date, there is no time.

Comment: @Dillon . . . There is a time, you just don't see it.  To see the time component, you either need to format the column as a string or as a timestamp.